# I keep getting an error in my !giverole command

Tags: discord, discord.js

When the owner of the server runs the command, it works but whenever any other admin/person with admin privileges uses it, the bot replies with "You do not have the required permissions"
Here is the code:

```
module.exports = {
    commands: ['giverole', 'addrole', 'ar','gr'], // The command names/aliases
    permissions: 'ADMINISTRATOR', //required permissions
    requiredRoles: ['Admins'], // required roles
    callback: (message, arguments) => {
      const targetUser = message.mentions.users.first()
      if (!targetUser) {
        message.channel.send('Please specify someone to give a role to.')
        return
      }
  
      arguments.shift()
  
      const roleName = arguments.join(' ')
      const { guild } = message
  
      const role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => {
        return role.name === roleName
      })
      if (!role) {
        message.channel.send(`There is no role with the name "${roleName}"`)
        return
      }
  
      const member = guild.members.cache.get(targetUser.id)
      member.roles.add(role)
  
      message.channel.send(`That user now has the "${roleName}" role`)
    },
  }
```

Edit: Here is the command base since it was asked for by @Caladan

```
 const validatePermissions = (permissions) => {
   const validPermissions = [
     'CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE',
     'KICK_MEMBERS',
     'BAN_MEMBERS',
     'ADMINISTRATOR',
     'MANAGE_CHANNELS',
     'MANAGE_GUILD',
     'ADD_REACTIONS',
     'VIEW_AUDIT_LOG',
     'PRIORITY_SPEAKER',
     'STREAM',
     'VIEW_CHANNEL',
     'SEND_MESSAGES',
     'SEND_TTS_MESSAGES',
     'MANAGE_MESSAGES',
     'EMBED_LINKS',
     'ATTACH_FILES',
     'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY',
     'MENTION_EVERYONE',
     'USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS',
     'VIEW_GUILD_INSIGHTS',
     'CONNECT',
     'SPEAK',
     'MUTE_MEMBERS',
     'DEAFEN_MEMBERS',
     'MOVE_MEMBERS',
     'USE_VAD',
     'CHANGE_NICKNAME',
     'MANAGE_NICKNAMES',
     'MANAGE_ROLES',
     'MANAGE_WEBHOOKS',
     'MANAGE_EMOJIS',
   ]
 
   for (const permission of permissions) {
     if (!validPermissions.includes(permission)) {
       throw new Error(`Unknown permission node "${permission}"`)
     }
   }
 }
 
 module.exports = (client, commandOptions) => {
   let {
     commands,
     expectedArgs = '',
     permissionError = 'You do not have permission to run this command.',
     minArgs = 0,
     maxArgs = null,
     cooldown = -1,
     requiredChannel = '',
     permissions = [],
     requiredRoles = [],
     callback,
   } = commandOptions
 
   // Ensure the command and aliases are in an array
   if (typeof commands === 'string') {
     commands = [commands]
   }
 
   console.log(`Registering command "${commands[0]}"`)
 
   // Ensure the permissions are in an array and are all valid
   if (permissions.length) {
     if (typeof permissions === 'string') {
       permissions = [permissions]
     }
 
     validatePermissions(permissions)
   }
```

Hope it helps in figuring out the issue.

Comment: Can you show your main file since it seems the unexpected behaviour might be coming from any role or permission check in that file?

Comment: Are you sure `permissions` is a string? Shouldn't it be an array as well? Like `permissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR']`. But @Caladan is right, we should see the part of your code where you use these `permissions`.

Comment: I added the main file, pls check